# How to select check boxes of recycler view from a pop menu in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a list of contacts with check boxes. Also I have to create a pop up menu onClick of a image on toolbar.

The pop up menu shows select all option.

So onclick of select all I want all check boxes of list to get selected.

Check box I have defined in an adapter.

Adapter:

```
    public class InviteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InviteAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList;
    private Context mContext;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        private CheckBox checkBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textContactName);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        }
    }


    public InviteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList) {
        this.contactArrayList = contactArrayList;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.invite_contact_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(contact.getmFullName());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactArrayList.size();
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
    public class InviteContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private InviteAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
    private ContactTableHelper contactDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invite_contacts);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

        mTitle.setText("Invite Contacts");


        if (toolbar != null) {

            toolbar.setTitle("");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        }
        ImageView back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageBack);

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                finish();

            }
        });

        final ImageView selectAll = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selectAll);

        selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(InviteContactsActivity.this,selectAll);

                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pop_up_menu, popup.getMenu());

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {



                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();
            }
        });


        contactDb = new ContactTableHelper(InviteContactsActivity.this);

        contactList = contactDb.getAllContacts();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(InviteContactsActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        adapter = new InviteAdapter(InviteContactsActivity.this, contactList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thank you..

EDIT:

I did this way:

In activity:

```
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    for (Contact contact: mContactList) {

                        contact.setSelected(true);


                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(); // how to do here?

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

In adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(contact.getmFullName());

    if(contact.getSelected() == true)
    {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }

}
```

Please check and let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in your adapter class :

```
public void toggleContactsSelection( boolean isSelected ) {
   for( Contact contact : contactArrayList ) {
       contact.setSelected(isSelected);
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged(); // OR you can use notifyItemRangeChanged - which ever suits your needs
}
```

In your onBindViewHolder method :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(contact.getmFullName());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(contact.getSelected());
}
```

Call the method of your adapter whenever you need to select all / unselect all contacts :

```
inviteAdapter.toggleContactsSelection(true); //Selects all contacts
inviteAdapter.toggleContactsSelection(false); //Unselect all contacts
```

Here's a link to methods involved in a Recycler adapter and their usage description :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Answer (score 1):

Your recycler adapter is backed by `contactList = contactDb.getAllContacts();` of class `Contact`. I suggest adding property like `isSelected` to the class, defaulting to `false`. After clicking on *"Select All"* iterate through whole contactList, set all `isSelected` to `true`. Now you just need to call `notifyDatasetChanged` on your adapter (possibly notifyItemRangeChanged with payload so you dont have to rebind all holders).

In `onBindViewHolder` you want to select Checkbox checked based on `isSelected` property.

Code style : dont mix using hungarian notation and not using it randomly. It makes everything harder to read. `mContext` vs `contactArrayList`, toolbar `mTitle` which isnt even member(?). Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: may i know how to call notifyItemRangeChanged with payload? What is the concept of payload? @poss

Comment: I am only getting option of notifyAll and notify on recyclerview. @poss

Comment: You dont call notify on recyclerView, you call it on adapter. Payload is described in documentation better than I can do it, but short version is notifying your adapter that objects backing them off didnt change, only some properities changed (like your checkbox). You dont have to bother with it for now, notifyDatasetChanged should work just fine. Also, In your adapter when you do `if(contact.getSelected() == true)`, you HAVE TO make an `else` case (because of recycling)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to implement one data model for checkbox and make it false. so by default checkbox will unchecked.

While you open a popup and click checkall option at that time change the value of model class and make it true and notify to adapter and you will get the the result.

ModelClass.java

```
public class ModelClass implements Serializable {
    public Boolean isChecked;

    public Boolean getChecked() {
       return isChecked:
    }

    public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
      isChecked = checked;
    }

}
```

initially, using `setCheked()` method set value of `isChecke = false` so you can retrive value of `isChecked` and get the value using  `getChecked()` method and you can access value in adapter class.

now, while you open popup menu at that time just use `setCheck()` method and setValue of `isChecked = true` and then notify adapter. thats it